# PDFlib error: Couldn't create virtual file '/pvf/image/test2.tiff' (name already exists)

Tags: pdflib

I have the problem in the title for whatever filename I choose.
The code is

```
            $this->pdf->create_pvf("/pvf/image/test2.tiff", $img_stream, "");
            $imgObj = $this->pdf->load_image("tiff", "/pvf/image/test2.tiff", "");
```

Can you help me?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

probably your code passes exactly at this point twice and thus tries to create the same file twice, which is then rejected.

For debugging purposes it may be helpful to enable PDFlib logging and then check yourself which PDFlib API calls you make at runtime.

It is best to enable logging as the first call to new PDFlib():

```
$pdf->set_option("logging {filename {C:/temp/PDFlib.log}}");
```

Please adjust the path and syntax if necessary. Logging is described in detail in the PDFlib Tutorial, Chapter 3.1.2 "Logging".